# Solving String Vibration Using Integral Transform

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

$$U_{tt} - c^2 U_{xx}= -g$$ where

BC: $U_{x}(0,t)=a\sin(ωt)$

IC: $U(x,0)=0$, $U_{t}(x,0)=0$

where $c, g, A$ and $ω$ are positive constants

Normally I wouldn't post for help here but I am absolutely desperate. I know how to solve this using the eigenvalue expansion method but I am absolutely terrible at Laplace and Fourier Transforms (Which i think i need to use one of the two).

Comment: Please use latex when posting on this forum http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry I will, it's just been a long time since i used latex and didn't even think to try typing in it.

Comment: This might help you http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124A/lecs/lec16.pdf